# How to count top-3 words used in column and store result in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe like this:

```
column_1:   column_2:    column_3:
  pizza       beer         nice, excellent, good
  pasta       beer         good, nice, great
  pizza       wine         great, nice
  fish        coffee       ok
```

I am trying to get the top-3 words that occur in column_3 and store them into a dictionary.

My expected output:

```
{ 'nice': 3,
  'good': 2,
  'great':2 }
```

What is the best way to do this? Or is it even possible?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `get_dummies` + `nlargest`

```
d=df['column_3:'].str.get_dummies(',').sum().nlargest(3).to_dict()
d
Out[225]: {'good': 2, 'great': 2, 'nice': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), to take to the `n` `most_common` strings in the third column having obtained a flat list from it:

```
from collections import Counter

l = df['column_3:'].str.cat(sep=',').split(',')
# ['nice', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'nice', 'great', 'great', 'nice', 'ok']
dict(Counter(l).most_common(3))
# {'nice': 3, 'good': 2, 'great': 2}
```